# Tooltip for flagging messages is wrong

Tags: bug, chat, flags

Not that I was actually going to flag it...but:

[image]

Note: My mouse was over "flag as spam/offensive". I don't think that's the same as "click to star".

Comment: This only happens in the dialog for pinned or starred messages, not in the regular one.